# How to access parent query arguments in GraphQL and Nestjs execution context

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs

Let's say we have a bookshop and an author entity, to show the author their earnings stat, we want to check if the authenticated user is indeed the author themselves. So we have:

```
  @UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard)
  @ResolveField(() => [Eearning], { name: 'earnings' })
  async getEarnings(
    @Parent() author: Author,
    @GqlUser() user: User,
  ) {
    if (user.id !== author.id)
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'Each author can only view their own data',
      );
    // rest of the function implementation
  }
```

We could query this:

```
query {
  author(id: "2bd79-6d7f-76a332b06b") {
    earnings {
      sells
    }
  }
}
```

Now imagine we want to use a custom Guard instead of that if statement. Something like below:

```
@Injectable()
export class AutherGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    // const artistId = ?
  }
}
```

How can I access the `id` argument given to the `author` query when `AutherGuard` is used for the `getEarnings` handler?

Comment: If an can only see their own earnings then no need to pass the author's id into the query. Just use the current user's id. (I make it a point never to pass the current user's id from client to server as it's redundant and creates opportunities for impersonation)

Comment: I agree. But the problem is that `author()` receives an `id` argument for public info that are accessible to all users. (like `author.books`). If I use the current author's id and they have entered an `id` other than their `id`, I still want to show a proper error instead of just passively returning their data (rather than the data of the id they have entered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how documented is that but the parent object can be accessed through the `getRoot` method:

```
const gqlContext = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
const root = gqlContext.getRoot();
const authorId = root.id;
```

In fact, we have a helper function that we use like this:

```
export function getArgs(context: ExecutionContext): any {
  if (context.getType<GqlContextType>() === "graphql") {
    const gqlContext = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return { ...gqlContext.getArgs(), $parent: gqlContext.getRoot() };
  } else if (context.getType() === "http") {
    return context.switchToHttp().getRequest().params;
  }
}

...
const args = getArgs(context);
const authorId = _.get(args, "$parent.id");
```

Comment: Well, this solves my problem! However, we still don't have access to the parent arguments there. If the argument passed is not retrievable by the parent object, then there isn't a way to get that argument. (Besides parsing the GraphQL query string, though)